# Programatically move the view of calendar and focus to the selected date (today for example) in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm trying programmatically in UWP, in event `onLoad` or whatever, move the view of the calendar control and set the focus to the selected date (in this case today date).

The reason for this is, for example, I open the page that has the calendar and the height of the app in that moment is smaller; there are times that the `today` date is not visible because it is above.

This is a screenshot when the app's height is small and the `today` day in calendar is not visible. In theory, it should be visible the first day of June, but I need move the view `onLoad` to make this but I don't know how.

[image: ui mockup]

Comment: You mean you want to programmatically move current calendar page to let today visible and set today as selected(which has a blue border)?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I'm looking to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
  <CalendarView x:Name="calendar" CalendarViewDayItemChanging="CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging"></CalendarView>

public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var parent = (todayItem.Parent as CalendarPanel);
            Rect rect = todayItem.TransformToVisual(parent).TransformBounds(new Rect(0,0, parent.ActualWidth, parent.ActualHeight ));
          (parent.Parent as ScrollViewer).ScrollToVerticalOffset(rect.Y);
            (parent.Parent as ScrollViewer).UpdateLayout();                           
        }

        CalendarViewDayItem todayItem;
        private void CalendarView_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            CalendarViewDayItem item = args.Item;
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date.Date;
            if (item.Date.DateTime.Date == date)
            {
                this.todayItem = item;
                ((item.Parent as CalendarPanel).Parent as ScrollViewer).ViewChanged += MainPage_ViewChanged;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to know, the 'MainPage_ViewChanged' has some code inside or that line is not necessary? Thanks for help

Comment: There is no method called Mainpage_ViewChanged

Comment: I asked because in the code has this line with the method 'MainPage_ViewChanged':  ((item.Parent as CalendarPanel).Parent as ScrollViewer).ViewChanged += MainPage_ViewChanged;

But let me try and tell you if work.

Comment: OK. That line is not required

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SetDisplayDate(DateTimeOffset date)` method in `CalendarView`

XAML

```
<CalendarView Loaded="CalendarViewLoaded"><CalendarView>
```

In Your Code:

```
private void CalendarViewLoaded(CalendarView cv, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    cv.SetDisplayDate(now);
}
```